# How to Update Visual Studio's "Cascading Style Sheet Version for Validation"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

In my Visual Studio 2010, the "Cascading Style Sheet Version For Validation" is targeting CSS version 2.1. How can I update VS to target CSS version 3?

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/27/html5-amp-css3-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx) implies that CSS3 validation is supported, but doesn't give any info on how to config VS2010 to target CSS3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just downloaded and installed Mojtaba.kaviani's "[CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210)" and now my VS2010 has Intellisense support for CSS3 validation.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is to go into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS and rename **css30.xml** to **css21.xml** (backup your files first of course).

That way, even though VS will show it is validating for version 2.1 it will really be validating for version 3.0