# Can the VS "cascading style sheet version for validation" default be changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, validation, css, default-value, toolstripdropdown

In reference to these [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6072446/304832) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3931801/304832), I have had CSS3 validation set up in VS2010 for a while.

However each time I close a CSS file, the "cascading style sheet version for validation" dropdown in the css toolstrip changes back from CSS 3.0 to CSS 2.1. When reopening a css file, I need to reselect CSS 3.0 to avoid the validation errors.

Is there any way to change the default? Even a registry hack would be acceptable at this point, it really is quite annoying.

There is another benefit of changing the default for this, when editing a cshtml file. Without a CSS file open, the validation target dropdown is grayed out. So to change it to 3.0 you have to have a CSS file open. Another annoyance.

I checked Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS, but there is no validation tab like there is for HTML.

Comment: I hate this, as well. :(

Comment: Good news is, this doesn't seem to be an issue in the VS 11 Beta.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is to go into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS and rename **css30.xml** to **css21.xml** (backup your files first of course).

That way, even though VS will show it is validating for version 2.1 it will really be validating for version 3.0